# Closure of $[1, 2] \cup [4, 5]$

Tags: general-topology

The closure of a set is the intersection of all closed sets in $X$ which contain the set.

In this the case of $[1, 2] \cup [4, 5]$ it seems to me that the closure will be $[1, 5]$, is that correct?

Comment: No! The finite union of closed sets is a closed set.

Comment: Closure with respect to which topology and in which set?

Answer (score 6):

No, this closure will be $[1,2] \cup [4,5]$, because the union of two closed sets is closed  and if the set $A$ is closed it is the smallest closed set wich contains itself.